# Gemfile.lock has different version of Rake in deployment environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake, bundler, gemfile

In short, the error message looks like following:

```
$ bundle install
rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.
```

And here is the explanation for this error:

- deployment server has `rake 0.9.2.2` installed
- application `Gemfile` has no required version number for `rake`
- developer's development environment has `rake` 0.9.2 installed and this version number is in `Gemfile.lock` file
- deployment server has a number of rails applications installed
- these applications are written by different programmers
- these programmers have different rake version installed in their development environment
- Some of them have `rake 0.9.2` and others have `rake 0.9.2.2`
- By reading [Yehuda Katz's Clarifying the Roles of the .gemspec and Gemfile](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/), `Gemfile.lock` file is in our subversion

---

**Possible Solutions:**

- error message could be avoided by running `bundle exec rake install` then `bundle update`
- error message could be avoided if we asked all developers to specify same version of rake in `Gemfile`
- ask all developers to use same version of rake

My question is: is this the correct solution here? or is there any correct solutions?

I am still not really sure the `Gemfile.lock` file should be in subversion.

Comment: Anther possible solution is using RVM: RVM lets you deploy each project with its own completely self-contained and dedicated environment--from the specific version of ruby, all the way down to the precise set of required gems to run your application.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely be checking in your Gemfile.lock. It contains the versions of your gem you know will work with your application. So when you bundle install on a different environment you know it should work.

Say a few months from now someone does a bundle install without a Gemfile.lock. They will get the latest version of gems in your Gemfile (at least the ones with a specified version) and there will be no guarantee that your app will even work with those gems. With a Gemfile.lock, there should be some assurance that your app should run, since anyone who's worked with it or ran tests on it should have had it in a passing state with those frozen gem versions.

To resolve your issue, I would do:

```
bundle update rake
```

and then commit Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. This way you're telling anyone who runs your app that you should be using 0.9.2.2 of rake. This is the version of rake you know will work with your app and your tests are run against this version.

To actually run the correct version you have a few options:

- bundle exec:

  ```
  $ bundle exec rake -T
  ```

Adding an alias to your .bash_profile, .zshrc, or .profile might also help:

```
# in .bash_profile
alias b="bundle exec"
$ b rake -T
```

- bundle binstubs

  ```
  # in your .bash_profile
  export PATH="./.bin:$PATH"
  $ bundle install --binstubs
  ```

This will install your Gemfile's binaries to ./bin directory and the path change will force your shell to check in ./bin first before looking in rvm or your gem install binaries. Remember to add 'bin' to your .gitignore file if you do this.

- [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) gem. This gem generates wrappers that tries to determine when to use bundle exec for you.

Comment: Good answer. However, I think the best solution for this is asking all developers to use same version of rake. By re-committing the updated Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to version control only soloved the problem for one application. On a production server, we have many applications. For some reason once you got rake 0.9.2.2 activated for one application. you will find other applications which use rake 0.9.2 fails to restart. So somehow, we need to keep the rake version  same for all applications. It might be not a technical problem but logical. I forgot to mention RVM in my question.

Comment: Continue... RVM creates separate gem set. It might be the technical solution for this problem. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The productivity drain your team will experience with trying to keep everyone on the same version of `rake` (2nd and 3rd solutions) and managing all the downstream conflicts could be very high.  It will also raise the level of developer frustration when they need to use gem/script/module XYZ but there is a problem with XYZ and the mandated version of `rake`.

As long as take steps to ensure the `bundle` commands execute efficiently in your environment, Solution 1 will make a much smaller negative impact on the productivity of your teams.  IMHO.

Comment: That is true. It is not easy. Developer will have frustration if one of the gem requires only works for either rake 0.9.2.2 or rake 0.9.2. And you cannot control other people's gems. I think I am now changing my conclusion: the best solution IN THEORY for this is asking all developers to use same version of rake. I am hoping RVM will solve the problem for me, Since it creates separate gem set for each rails application.